# SVG path is not displayed properly while creating PDF using PhantomJS on Chromium / Safari

Tags: pdf, svg, safari, phantomjs, chromium

I am creating a PDF using PhantomJS. My code is :

```
phantom.create(function(err, ph) {
        console.log("err,", err);
        if (!err) {
            ph.createPage(function(err, page) {
                page.settings = {
                    loadImages: true,
                    localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled: true,
                    javascriptEnabled: true,
                    loadPlugins: false
                };
                var width = (parseFloat(propertyData.width) - 2) + propertyData.scaleUnit;
                var height = (parseFloat(propertyData.height) - 1) + propertyData.scaleUnit;
                // page.set('viewportSize', {
                //     width: width,
                //     height: height
                // });
                page.set('paperSize', {
                    width: width,
                    height: height,
                    border: '1cm',
                    margin: {
                        top: '50px',
                        left: '20px',
                        right: '20px',
                        bottom: '20px'
                    },
                    format: 'A4',
                    orientation: 'portrait',
                });
                template = '<svg id="space-bg-wrapper" class="svg-view" x="20%" y="175px" height="500" width="500" viewBox="0 0 792 612" style="stroke-opacity:0.2"> <g id="svg-bg-view" class="svg-view"> <g transform="translate(-0.96746826171875,-42.793792724609375)rotate(180,387.48394775390625,194.16751098632812)skewX(0)scale(1,1.0306836366653442)"> <path d="M182.50403600841202 80.38036978292318 L172.70506286621094 80.14508819580078 L172.70506286621094 114.00178527832031 L181.7335205078125 114.00178527832031 A4.343611657245171 4.343611657245171 0 0 1 185.92530822753906 118.51600646972656 A40.441789212785444 40.441789212785444 0 0 0 210.43109130859375 146.56869506835938 L252.34890747070312 158.1767120361328 A59.57813444575779 59.57813444575779 0 0 1 279.7566833496094 178.49072265625 A406.3642033922339 406.3642033922339 0 0 0 326.1887512207031 249.10610961914062 A32.97772024752448 32.97772024752448 0 0 0 352.3067626953125 263.6161193847656 L430.01593017578125 262.3263244628906 A114.28025350018537 114.28025350018537 0 0 0 474.4089660644531 252.00811767578125 L532.448974609375 226.5349884033203 L542.122314453125 221.37586975097656 L588.8768310546875 193.6456298828125 A133.6022573445588 133.6022573445588 0 0 1 608.009033203125 186.03514099121094 A8.782023371505137 8.782023371505137 0 0 1 618.3994750976562 197.51495361328125 A46.67013003017425 46.67013003017425 0 0 1 600.3425903320312 222.34320068359375 L478.775146484375 289.60009765625 A142.1379078281504 142.1379078281504 0 0 1 325.35864251852036 291.86439372375736 A102.52202434832462 102.52202434832462 0 0 1 302.2120666503906 267.98583984375 A969.0369374911932 969.0369374911932 0 0 1 269.0889587402344 207.3537139892578 A85.68694938991193 85.68694938991193 0 0 0 232.87342834472656 172.37100219726562 L189.541748046875 161.02517700195312 A32.988879133123916 32.988879133123916 0 0 1 166.66075134277344 143.63380432128906 A99.77487323751137 99.77487323751137 0 0 1 156.55538940429688 113.87913513183594 A243.7778168615004 243.7778168615004 0 0 1 155.8371124267578 84.31023406982422 A23.21498547957365 23.21498547957365 0 0 1 176.3285369873047 62.9766960144043 L181.3812255859375 62.9766960144043 A6.379072891303258 6.379072891303258 0 0 1 186.714599609375 70.27500915527344 L186.714599609375 76.73121643066406 A4.890656798052708 4.890656798052708 0 0 1 182.50404357910156 80.38037109375" stroke="#000" stroke-dasharray="0" stroke-width="1" marker-start="none" marker-end="none" flag="polygon" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" fill="#fff" class="" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path> </g> </g> </svg>';

                page.set('content', template, function(error) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log('Error setting content: ', error);
                        res.status('400').send("OK");
                    } else {
                        console.log("content has been set");
                    }
                });
                page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
                    page.render("temp1.pdf", function(error) {
                        if (error) console.log('Error rendering PDF: %s', error);
                        else {
                            console.log("PDF GENERATED : ", status);
                            if (page) {
                                page.close();
                            }
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                ph.exit();
                                return callback(true);
                            }, 500);

                        }

                    });

                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log("error while creating page", err);
        }

    });

} catch (e) {
    console.log("Error in renderPDF ", e);
}
```

The PDF is generated successfully but doesn't display properly on Chromium and Safari browser. Attached are sample images.[image]
PDF is shown Chromium:

PDF is shown  Firefox: [image]

Answer (score 1):

The path's attributes should be in a specific order to create/display the pdf on "safari/chromium" browser without any error. By changing the order in required format will resolve the issue and will create the pdf successfully. You can refer following link [path Vector link](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/overview-shape-layers-paths-vector.html) for the reference.